# Wordpress single login in multiple wordpress projects?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have set of wordpress projects which are individually build. each and every project has database. There is a Major project others are sub projects. I want to login first my Major project and then auto login others.
Please Help Me...

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to login to multiple WordPress sites at once. I wonder why would you want to do that.

(I wanted to post this answer as comment but I have not enough reputation.)

Comment: This might be helpful: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131399/share-login-data-cookies-between-multiple-installations